# Should we shut the [system] down?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just bumped into a [tag wiki suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/866392) for the [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) tag. The tag sounds too generic, and the [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) shows it's being used on several different contexts. Should it be burninated? If not, what would be the valid usage?

---

I just found another one that seems to fall into the same category: [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) (but that's more widely used (8.3k versus 1.5k questions).

Comment: wow, what are the odds we would both post about this at once? Great minds think alike :-)

Comment: You were faster rejecting the edit, I was faster posting here :)

Comment: A few of them seem to be about the `system()` function in C (or equivalents in other languages).

Comment: @hammar Looks like a perfectly legitimate use for that tag. So maybe the wiki should be about that.

Comment: You forgot to [send out the signal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XfFNG.png)

Comment: Please change the title to "Should we shut the [system] down?".

Comment: Hahaha go ahead @dorukayhan, I'll approve your edit.

Comment: Well, the problem is you have to do that because suggested edits are disabled on Meta.

Answer (score 7):

The only use I could see for it is to indicate that a question is about [system programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming), but it's still at best a meta tag when used in that context and would need to be renamed.

<strike>The same holds true for the[application] tag</strike> (now gone).

I don't see any practical use for either distinction, so yes - I think both are candidates for removal as cleanup of other, more problematic tags like [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) continues.

We've had several large meta tag cleanup efforts, but those cats came back, the very next day with fur of a different color. The idea of [reviewing based on tags was proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146156/review-based-on-tag), however I think what we need is [review ***of*** new tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148300/add-a-review-queue-for-new-and-for-rarely-used-tags) integrated into the new review system. It's much better to catch these before they're applied on a massive scale, we can't keep spending energy on massive cleanups as we have been.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds burninate-worthy to me, unless someone wants to do the work of deducing what some major sub-contexts are and applying the correct new sub-context tag to the corresponding questions... which sounds like an awful amount of work. I suppose it's not the philosophy here, but it might be thought to be ok if many people are using it in a way that makes sense, and a searcher on multiple tags might find it useful. E.g., if an OS or framework has a "System" directory, or an API has a module named "System", or something.

Comment: The community has been manually cleaning up worse stuff like the homework tag. Question is, is this tag worth it?